# Swift - Timer.scheduledTimer.timeInterval issue - increasing Nodes spawn rate

Tags: swift, timer

I'm making a simple SpriteKit game where items falls down, and i need to manage items spawn speed depending on current score. But i have an issue with Timer.scheduledTimer.

```
func manageItemsSpawnSpeed() {
    if score < 10 {
        itemsSpawnTimeInterval = 1.0
    } else if score >= 10 && score < 20 {
        itemsSpawnTimeInterval = 0.9
    } else if score >= 20 && score < 50 {
        itemsSpawnTimeInterval = 0.8
    } else if score >= 50 && score < 100 {
      itemsSpawnTimeInterval = 0.7
    }...
```

spawnItems() - spawn the items at the top of the screen at the random position

```
func spawnItems() {
    self.scene?.addChild(itemController.spawnItems())
}
```

Here is items spawn timer, currently i call it only at the start of the game

```
func theSpawntimer() {
    Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: TimeInterval(itemsSpawnTimeInterval), target: self, selector: #selector(GameplayScene.spawnItems), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
```

So, when the score changes - itemsSpawnTimeInterval updates well, but everytime when i call theSpawntimer() again, it also launches additional spawnItems(), and instead of increasing the spawn speed - it makes items rain in game.

Please advise how can i call theSpawntimer() everytime when itemsSpawnTimeInterval changes without recalling spawnItems().
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue, I refused to use a scheduledTimer. And instead i used SKAction:

```
func theSpawner() {
    removeAction(forKey: spawnKey) // remove previous action if running.
    let spawnAction = SKAction.run(spawnItems)
    let spawnDelay = SKAction.wait(forDuration: itemsSpawnTimeInterval)
    let spawnSequence = SKAction.sequence([spawnAction, spawnDelay])
    run(SKAction.repeatForever(spawnSequence), withKey: spawnKey) // run action with key so you can cancel it later
```